# Compare a Date inside a ArrayList customized

Tags: java, arraylist, compare

How can I compare date values inside an `ArrayList`?

I created this:

```
ArrayList<newContact> contactList
```

Then inside the constructor I got as a parameter:

```
(String address, String body, long date)
```

I would try something like this:

```
Collections.sort(contactList.get(i).date);
```

But I know it's wrong, so if someone could help me thank you :)

Comment: `sort()` needs the *list* to be sorted, and if you don't want to sort by the "natural" order of `newContact`, then it also needs a `Comparator` as the second parameter. You're trying to give it a `long` value. How do you sort a single integer value?

Comment: FYI: In Java, class names should always start with an uppercase letter, so it should be `NewContact`, not `newContact`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can use `Collections.sort(T t, Comparator<? extends T> compare)`.
Create a new Comparator class as follows. The logic will be based on how u want to sort(ascending, descending)

```
class CompareDate implements Comparator<NewContact>
{
    public int compare(NewContact c1, NewContact c2)
    {
        if (c1.getDate() > c2.getDate()
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (c1.getDate() == c2.getDate()
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can do

```
contactList.sort(Comparators.comparing(c -> c.getDate()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<CreateMessageAdapter>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(CreateMessageAdapter c1, CreateMessageAdapter c2) {
        if (c1.getDate() > c2.getDate())
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (c1.getDate() == c2.getDate())
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return -1;
    }
});
```